# Python: How do I select a range in a csv file. I can select the min and max but am confused on the range

Tags: python

I am able to use functions to call certain values and am able to print min and max values to get value of a csv file. How can I get something in the middle of min and max?

this value

```
max_mileage = max(mileage_list)[0]
min_mileage = min(mileage_list)[0]
```

prints out my min and max values but I want to select two values in the middle of those. How do I do it.

Comment: Example(s) of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: Also we'd love to know what datatype `mileage_list` is, as this can be critical for teaching you how to interact with it. What code did you use to generate it? What's the (general) format of your CSV? (e.g. are all the fields text? numbers?) Oftentimes the more information you can give us, the better.

Comment: Remove the min and max elements of the list, then use `random.choice()` to pick a different element.

Comment: Barmar, I think the root issue is that they're not quite sure how to get any non-min/max element, not that they want a random element

Comment: Could this be an example of where 2d indexing is needed? such as e.g. `mileage_list[2][1]`

Comment: For example the CSV file shows that some vehicle gets 45MPG which is what the max(mileage_list)[0] which is the max. I am trying to print something that is below that mileage. Maybe the user wants to select 34MPG how can print 34MPG vehicles

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.randint`:

```
import random
start, end = min_mileage, max_mileage 
rand_numbers = [random.randint(start, end) for i in range(2)] #if you want 2 numbers between min and max
```